# SQLite update in MacOSX

Tags: sqlite

I use `SQLite 3.6.7` and I want to update it. Can anyone say how to update my SQLite to the latest version step by step  ...

I'm developing `OS X` apps. For this, I'm using `SQLite 3.6.7`. But I came to know that I can't directly use foreign keys so I want to update my SQLite to the latest version ... Can anyone help me out with this by mentioning the step by step procedure to do it ...

Comment: Foreign key enforcement support was added in 3.6.19, though it's still switched off by default for backward compatibility. (Syntactically, they've been supported for much longer IIRC.)

Answer (score 1):

Download the "amalgamation" [tarball](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) for UNIX-like systems.

Extract the contents.

Launch Terminal, and cd to the extracted directory.

Type:

```
CFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-arch i686 -arch x86_64' ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking

make

make install
```

Strictly speaking, the first line above could just be `./configure`. The `CFLAGS` `LDFLAGS` `--disable-dependency-tracking` thing isn't necessary, but it makes a library that can be used from both 32-bit and 64-bit apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not update the SQLite version in you mac. Will you force all of your users to update to the lastest version of SQLite?.

in you project, create a folder named "sqlite" or other name. Download the lastest SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.3.tar.gz), unzip them and add them to your project. In your source files, use `#import "sqlite3.h"` instead of `#import <sqlite3.h>` (which links to the installed version of SQLite)